# Trying to find Duplicate comma delimited texts in each cell of a column

Tags: vba, loops, duplicates, csv

I have the following macro that I got from someone, and trying to modify it to suit my purpose.

I'm trying to alter this macro to find and highlight cells that have duplicate values within each cell,
for example, it should highlight B62 and B63 (green),
and color font red the duplicate values (i.e. B_HWY_1010 in B62, and B_HWY_1015 in B63)

[image]

```
Sub Dupes()
  Dim d As Object
  Dim a As Variant, itm As Variant
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim bColoured As Boolean
 
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set rng = Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  a = rng.Value
  For i = 1 To UBound(a)
    For Each itm In Split(a(i, 1), ",")
      d(itm) = d(itm) + 1
    Next itm
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 1 To UBound(a)
    k = 1
    bColoured = False
    For Each itm In Split(a(i, 1), ",")
      If d(itm) > 1 Then
        If Not bColoured Then
          rng.Cells(i).Interior.Color = vbGreen
          bColoured = True
        End If
        rng.Cells(i).Characters(k, Len(itm)).Font.Color = RGB(244, 78, 189)
      End If
      k = k + Len(itm) + 1
    Next itm
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help or advise is appreciated.

Comment: What "Duplicate comma delimited texts" does mean? Only one of the delimited elements to be the same with another one from another cell? Or the whole string, even if it contains comma delimiters to be the same?

Comment: @FaneDuru in simple words I'm trying to find duplicates within a single cell, NOT compared with any other cell.

So if you have a look at the image in the post, Row 62 has a value entered twice separated by a comma, so in this case I want the macro to identify it and highlight it

Comment: What if there are two such identic strings (in a cell) and a third one different from it? will it be marked as duplicate?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes It must identify this as well.

Let's say a cell has: A, B, C, B
then it should identify and highlight the 2nd "B"

Comment: Highlight **the second "B"**, or the cell in discussion? What the green interior color does mean in your picture?

Comment: The macro above is highlighting the wrong cells,
it should highlight green the cells which have a duplicate value,
and change the font to red the value which is duplicate.

So let's say again:
Cell A, B ,C, B
This cell should be green, and the 2nd "B" should be red text.

Comment: To highlight the whole cell is not so complicated, but searching between the string characters to do it for each case takes more time than my availability... Maybe somebody else will have more. Anyhow, no need of any dictionary. This object makes sense only to determine unique cases and keep the number of occurrences (in such a case). Then, you shouldn't show us a wrong layout not explaining what is it about. You should show only **what you need**.

Comment: @FaneDuru, coloring the text can be a helpful feature but can do with just the highlighting.
I'm sorry if adding that layout was confusing, I tried to be as clear as possible

Comment: @FaneDuru you don't need to search for the items if you keep summing up the length of the already processed string, so you always know where to start coloring when you come across a repetition. See my answer.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I had to leave my office and I will do it immediately. In the meantime I also prepared an answer, without using a dictionary. I will post it in one minute. Then,  I will be driving...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do that

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Range("A1:A10")
        HighlightRepetitions Cell, ", "
    Next Cell
End Sub

Private Sub HighlightRepetitions(ByVal Cell As Range, ByVal Delimiter As String)
    If Cell.HasFormula Or Cell.HasArray Then Exit Sub ' don't run on formulas

    Dim Dict As Object
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim Data() As String
    Data = Split(Cell.Value, Delimiter)  ' split data in the cell by Delimiter 
    
    Dim StrLen As Long  ' length of the string that was already processed
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)  ' loop through all data items
        Dim DataLen As Long
        DataLen = Len(Data(i))  'get length of current item
        
        If Dict.Exists(Data(i)) Then
            ' item is a repetition: color it
            Cell.Characters(StrLen + 1, DataLen).Font.Color = vbRed
            Cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Else
            ' item is no repetition: add it to the dictionary
            Dict.Add Data(i), Data(i)
        End If
        
        StrLen = StrLen + DataLen + Len(Delimiter)  ' calculate the length of the processed string and add length of the delimiter
    Next i
End Sub
```

The following items would be colored:

[image]

You can turn `ScreenUpdating` off before looping in `Sub Example()` and turn on after the loop to stop it from flickering. Note this will not run on formuas, as parts of formula results cannot be colored. This can be prevented by using `If Cell.HasFormula Or Cell.HasArray Then Exit Sub` as first line.

Comment: Nice... Voted it up. I understand that he wants bolded both occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next code, too:

```
Sub findComaDelDuplicates()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, itm, arrInt, i As Long, rngS As Range, pos As Long
 Dim arrDif As Long, j As Long, startPos As Long, arrPos, k As Long, mtch
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 With sh.Range("B1", Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp))
    arr = .value               'put the range value in an array to make the iteration faster
    .ClearFormats            'clear previous format
    .Font.Color = vbBlack 'make the font color black
 End With
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)           'iterate between the array elements:
    arrInt = Split(arr(i, 1), ",")       'split the content by comma delimiter
    ReDim arrPos(UBound(arrInt)) 'redim the array keeping elements already formatted
    For Each itm In arrInt            'iterate between the comma separated elements
        arrDif = UBound(arrInt) - 1 - UBound(Filter(arrInt, itm, False)) 'find how many times an element exists
        If arrDif > 0 Then            'if more then an occurrence:
            If rngS Is Nothing Then             'if range to be colored (at once) does not exist:
                Set rngS = sh.Range("B" & i)  'it is crated
            Else
                Set rngS = Union(rngS, sh.Range("B" & i)) 'a union is made from the previous range and the new one
            End If
            mtch = Application.match(itm, arrPos, 0)       'check if the itm was already processed:
            If IsError(mtch) Then                                'if itm was not processed:
                For j = 1 To arrDif + 1                          'iterate for number of occurrences times
                    If j = 1 Then startPos = 1 Else: startPos = pos + 1 'first time, inStr starts from 1, then after the first occurrence
                    pos = InStr(startPos, sh.Range("B" & i).value, itm)  'find first character position for the itm to be colored
                    sh.Range("B" & i).Characters(pos, Len(itm)).Font.Color = vbRed 'color it
                Next j
                arrPos(k) = itm      'add the processed itm in the array
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Erase arrInt                      'clear the array for the next cell value
 Next i
 If Not rngS Is Nothing Then rngS.Interior.Color = vbGreen        'color the interior cells of the built range
End Sub
```

Attention: The above code puts the range in an array to iterate much faster. But, if the range does not start form the first row, the cells to be processed must be obtained by adding to `i` the rows up to the first of the range. The code can be adapted to make this correlation, but I am too lazy to do it now...:)

Comment: Nice job, looks like this works too. It just colors the first repetition. Instead leaving the first black and color the others it colores the first and leaves the last black. • He said `A, B, C, B then it should identify and highlight the 2nd "B"` your's colors the first B instead of the second. • But actually nice to have both ways covered in answers.

Comment: excellent, this one works well too.
Thank you both

Comment: Not optimized, tested only once, it worked on my sample and not tried on different variations, now I am driving... :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Changed the code logic, in order to color in red all duplicate occurrences.

Comment: @M Muaz: Changed the code logic, in order to color in red all duplicate occurrences. It should be fast enough for a big range, too.